# Sequelize nested eager loading find all where nested association doesn't match

Tags: sql, sequelize.js, graphql, graphql-js

I am attempting to set up a custom permissions module on our site and am relatively new to sequelize and how to perform basic nested eager loading operations.

The way I have things set up is I have three models: `Permission`, `PermissionDirectory`, and `User`. The permissions are in a list, nested inside of their `belongsTo` relationship with a directory. I have a filter on the list that filters by whether a user is "Allowed" or "Denied" the permission. Users have a many-to-many relationship with permissions and I am determining whether they are "Allowed" a permission by if the association exists between them or not.

The page in question is when filtering a specific user's permissions. Filtering for whether the user is "Allowed" the permission is simple enough:

```js
const directories = await models.PermissionDirectory.findAll({
  limit,
  offset,
  where: { ["$permissions.users.id$"], userId },
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Permission,
      include: [{
        model: models.User
      }]
    },
  ]
});

return directories;
```

But filtering by "Denied" has proven difficult. Performing the opposite conditional will return the permissions that other users have rather than returning the permissions the target user (specified with the `userId` parameter) does not have.

`where: { ["$permissions.users.id$"], { [Op.ne]: userId }}`

This doesn't work. Take the example of if I were querying to get all the permissions User1 was "Denied". If User1 had Permission1 and User2 also had Permission1, Permission1's directory would get all the permissions that had users that were not User1. Since User2 was associated with Permission1 and `User1.id != User2.id`, Permission1 would be included in the response.

I can, however, get the desired effect by first querying for all the permissions that have the userId, making a list of their id's, and then performing a second query that gets the permissions whose id is not in that list... but this requires two calls rather than a single one.

Tl;dr I am looking for a way to make a nested eager loading query with permission directories on the top level that will return only the directories/permissions that do NOT have the given user associated with them.

Comment: Made some progress trying to build queries a little bit more directly following some methods described in this [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3961). It seems as though sequelize may have some short comings when it comes to query building.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much scouring of the internets and many dead ends I think I know the unfortunate answer to the question: sequelize isn't great at building complex queries.

To add further clarity to my question, this outline of [mysql join types](http://stevestedman.com/2015/03/mysql-join-types-poster/) depicts my scenario as an [Anti Semi Join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b61Py.png).

In order to achieve this sql query in sequelize I would need to be able to perform a sub-query which doesn't appear to be natively supported by sequelize (gauging from the lack of movement on issue [#3961](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3961)).

Using `sequelize.literal` inside the where statement seems to work just fine for my needs but it would be nice if sequelize had incorporated all of the join types into their functionality from the get go rather than only having Inner Joins and Left Joins supported. Seems like kind of an oversight to me.

Comment: have u figured out something additional to that? I'm looking for way to use `where` condition on `eager nested` columns.